# Php insert from json data to mysql from top to bottom in while

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

I have a problem - I need to insert data from json to mysql but it's inserting last videoId and it's 3 same videoId's inserted 7EDPROQa4i0. I need to insert from top to bottom from json to database. I cannot understand what's wrong

JSON DATABASE

```
{
  "resultsPerPage": 3
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "kHPqpxDE50c"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw",
    },
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "videoId": "DbAlCl3kk-M"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw",
    },
   }
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "7EDPROQa4i0"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw",
    },
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
    $loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT channelid, videoId FROM users ORDER BY id")
    or die (mysqli_error($conn));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
    {
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$row['channelid'].'&maxResults=3&key=KEY';
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $json = json_decode($content, true);

        foreach($json['items'] as $row)
        {
            $channelid = $row['snippet']['channelId'];
            $videoId = $row['id']['videoId'];
            $videoId1 = $row['id']['videoId'];
            $videoId2 = $row['id']['videoId'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, videoId, videoId1, videoId3) VALUES('$channelid', '$videoId', '$videoId1', '$videoId2')    
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid='$channelid', videoId='$videoId', videoId1='$videoId1', videoId2='$videoId2';
            ";
            mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
            if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
            {
                die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn));
            }
        }
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The `...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` is updating data.

Comment: but json data it's always updating, and i need fresh data. how to combine that?

Comment: Without the schema for your database table and what keys are unique (specifically) who can say.  For example if `channelid` is Unique by itself then that's a big problem.  It should be a compound unique key with `channelid` and `videoId` together.  or just `videoId`

Comment: You also have some naming conventions stuff I would sort out for example `channelid` vs `videoId` that would drive me mad.  And this is probably an issue `videoId='$videoId', videoId1='$videoId1', videoId2='$videoId2'`  if you limit your data to only 3 videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your problem

```
foreach($json['items'] as $row){
    ...
    $videoId = $row['id']['videoId'];
    $videoId1 = $row['id']['videoId'];
    $videoId2 = $row['id']['videoId'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, videoId, videoId1, videoId3) VALUES('$channelid', '$videoId', '$videoId1', '$videoId2')    
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid='$channelid', videoId='$videoId', videoId1='$videoId1', videoId2='$videoId2';
        ";
    ...
}
```

Basically what happens is take your first JSON data (I'll focus just on the Values part):

```
 //iteration 1
 VALUES('UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw', 'kHPqpxDE50c', 'kHPqpxDE50c', 'kHPqpxDE50c')
//iteration 2
 VALUES('UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw', 'DbAlCl3kk-M', 'DbAlCl3kk-M', 'DbAlCl3kk-M')
//iteration 3
 VALUES('UCiP20o92_7jUYwj-ulVLifw', '7EDPROQa4i0', '7EDPROQa4i0', '7EDPROQa4i0')
```

Now think what happens. Because of how you table is setup(improperly I may add), I'd be willing to bet that `chanelid` is unique.  So each loop you overwrite the id's from the previous loop.

> it's 3 same videoId's inserting 7EDPROQa4i0

Which by the way is "Exactly" what you see happen.

To fix it you have to insert/update after the JSON loop. By building an array of video Ids that we can insert in one query.  You don't need 1 query for each loop of the JSON data (the way it's setup).

Like this:

```
$loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT channelid, videoId FROM users ORDER BY id")
or die (mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
{
    $channelid = $row['channelid'];
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelid .'&maxResults=3&key=KEY';
    $content = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json = json_decode($content, true);    

    if(!isset($json['items'])) continue; //skip if no items

    $videos = ['videoId'=>'','videoId1'=>'','videoId2'=>''];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($json['items'] as $items)
    {
        $key  = 0==$i ? 'videoId' : 'videoId'.$i;
        $videos[$key] = $items['id']['videoId']; 
        ++$i;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, videoId, videoId1, videoId3) VALUES('$channelid', '{$videos['videoId']}', '{$videos['videoId1']}', '{$videos['videoId2']}')    
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid=VALUES(channelid), videoId=VALUES(videoId), videoId1=VALUES(videoId1), videoId2=VALUES(videoId2);
        ";
    mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
```

That takes care of the immediate issue.  However there is a much bigger issue here, which is how your table is setup and how you are using it.  The way you have it you are limited to only 3 video and even if that is all you need, at some point you might want more. Everyone always wants more, it's a given.  To update it to have 4 or 5 or 6 requires you add additional columns in, which is bad.

**Deeper Issues**

A better way is to use 1 Row per video.  So how do we do that?

The first thing to do is export this table (so you have a backup)

Then change the index for `channelid` to a compound (composite) "Unique" index, that has 2 fields both the `channelid` and `videoId` as the fields. Both of these have to be the same for the row to be considered a duplicate.

Next add a simple index (non-unique) back on `channelId`.  You want it to have it's own index because for the compound one to work generally you'll wan't to supply both fields (in the order of the index).  That said I do forget (between the DB and some other things like Mongo), so you may be able to use one if it's the first one.  You can always do explain and make sure it uses it. Anyway, you want that index because we are going to be using that to do lookups and well indexing it is good.

Next you will have to get rid of `videoId1` and `videoId2` completely.  If you have data in there you don't want to lose you can make a migration script that will pull the values out of those 2 fields and create a new row for them.

Then onto the code.

```
$loop = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT channelid FROM users ORDER BY id")
or die (mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
{
    $channelid = $row['channelid'];
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelid .'&maxResults=3&key=KEY';
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    if(!isset($json['items'])) continue; //skip if no items

    foreach($json['items'] as $items)
    {
        $videoId = $items['id']['videoId'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, videoId) VALUES('$channelid', '$videoId')    
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE channelid=VALUES(channelid), videoId=VALUES(videoId);
        ";
        mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
        if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
        {
            die('Error : ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }
    }
}
```

This is much closer to your original, but we use only one field in the first query and `DISTINCT`.  The rest should be self explanatory.

When you pull the data out, you'll just have to loop though the results as each row will be 1 video.  It will make things simpler in the long run, promise.

**Other things**

You also have SQL Injection issues, which is so so as this is probably less hackable, but why risk it.  Anytime you concatenate data into a query you open the door of SQLInjection.  Even if the data is 100% safe, you lose nothing by always preparing your queries.  There is plenty of tutorials on how to do this.

You can use `VALUES(column)` in the on duplicate part, which I did.  This saves us from having to duplicate the variable (which shouldn't be here) but even when you prepare it, it will make it easier.

Naming conventions, such as `channelid` vs `videoId` vs `channelId`.  It may seem like not a big deal, but it really is.  While everyone has their own way of doing it the most important part is "be consistent".  I prefer no-caps, underlines for spaces, plural table names.  So for me these would be `channel_id`, `video_id`.  By knowing this and being consistant I don't have to look back at the schema of a table I made a year ago and wonder if it's `channelid`, `ChannelId`, `channelID`, `channelId` or `channel_id`.  AS you can see just looking there is more variation in the cased versions then the lowercase version (4+ vs 2). Spaces in column name are a non-starter in MySQL as you have to escape them with backtics so that's never a question.

You were overwriting the `$row` variable in the inner loop, the one for JSON, so I changed that to `$items` instead. You also don't need the `channelid` from the JSON because you already have it in the query (and the url).

Enjoy!

Comment: Now i get this problem and repeating this error 3 rows 6errors
Notice: Undefined index: snippet in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\video.php on line 12
Notice: Undefined index: videoId1 in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\video.php on line 21
12: $channelid = $row['snippet']['channelId'];
21: $sql = "INSERT INTO users(channelid, videoId, videoId1, videoId3) VALUES('$channelid', '{$videos['videoId']}', '{$videos['videoId1']}', '{$videos['videoId2']}')

Comment: That is because you are overwriting $row something I missed, sorry.   I updated the answer.

Comment: Now good without error but inserting just one array videoId if i $i change to -> $i++  then i get two arrays videoId ant videoId2 but videoId it's clear "null" how it's works. but almost working

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/2436650ec9805ae8f1ac830195b55db0.png / / /
https://pastebin.com/Qrb22nNV now without errors, butu somewhere videoId1 disappear :D

Comment: Well you changed my code for one thing [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d39bfb9c49ee02f16c3543e7dd19f36a6359348)  The first iteration $i is set to 1 but it dosn't show because the if $i == 0; on the next iteration $i is already 1 then gets set to 2

Comment: Ohh yes now working my bad thanks i want shall repay you for your big work !

Comment: And last thing, how get latest (from up) publishedAt array he like channelId in json but publishedAt

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that, you may want to submit it as a separate question.  Often branching off of one problem to another only muddies things up.